# Convert var to List<T> in c#

Tags: c#, linq, delegates

I am unable to convert back `var` to `List<CustomObject>`.

```
private void PopulateChart(List<CustomObject> rawData)
 {
   var groupedByCategory1 = rawData.GroupBy(co => co.Category1)
   //List<CustomObject> data = groupedByCategory1.GroupBy(co => co.Category1).ToList();    
 }
```

Note: From `rawData` I have to get Groupby data. using that result again I have to group the data.

Comment: What list are you trying the get? `GroupBy` returns a list of group-by results, so essentially a list of lists. What is the logic to turn that into a normal list again?

Comment: After using group by you can't get the same type, it'll be a differnt one

Comment: i think its easier if you tell what result you expect

Answer (score 1):

Linq `GroupBy` returns `System.Linq.IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey,TSource>>`. So, you should select some data from groups:

```
List<CustomObject> data = groupedByCategory1
     .GroupBy(co => co.Category1)
     .Select(grp => new CustomObject 
          {
              Category1 = grp.Key
          }
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var data = groupedByCategory1
         .GroupBy(co => co.Category1)
         .Select(grp => new 
              {
                  Category1 = grp.Key// This is the key that you used to group
                  groupList=grp.ToList();//This will be the list of CustomObject
              }
         .ToList();
```

Actually, `GroupBy` groups your list into another list where `Category1` is same.

You can access it as shown below

```
foreach (var group in data)
{// This group is List<CustomObject>. If you don't want to access it like this, whats the meaning of group by?
  var groupKey=group.Category1;
  foreach(CustomObject myObj in group.groupList)
   {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
var groupedByCategory1 = rawData
   .GroupBy(co => co.Category1)    
   .SelectMany(c => c)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Your linq returned `List<List<T>>`.

Comment: I have edited the answer to use SelectMany... This will convert List<List<T>> to a List<T>

Comment: But it will be meaning less if not list<list<T>>

Comment: @Suresh Kumar Veluswamy, why in this case use `GroupBy`?

Comment: @Alexander Actually the problem is with the OP.

Comment: It does not become meaningless...SelectMany is used to combine the groups into a single array. The data will be grouped first and them they are combined to a single List instead of List<List>... The requirement is to convert it to a single List and not List<List>

Comment: @Suresh Kumar Veluswamy, `GroupBy` + `SelectMany` + `ToList` = `ToList`, do not you think so?

Comment: @alexander You will be getting a list with grouped items listed together. This will be the only difference if he do `GroupBy + SelectMany + ToList`. But the result won't make sense if further data manipulation is required. Also,`order by` can be used for this purpose.