# How can I Convert Class as IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

Is it possible to convert class as `IEnumerable`?

```
 private SeriesMapping CreateSeriesMapping(string category, string value, string stackKey, CustomObject itemsSource)
    {
        var data= (IEnumerable)itemsSource;
        SeriesMapping successMapping = new SeriesMapping() { SeriesDefinition = new StackedBar100SeriesDefinition() { StackGroupName = stackKey } };
        successMapping.ItemMappings.Add(new ItemMapping(category, DataPointMember.XCategory));
        successMapping.ItemMappings.Add(new ItemMapping(value, DataPointMember.YValue));
        successMapping.ItemsSource = data; // after conversion i did not any data.

     // successMapping.ItemsSource = itemsSource; //if i use this i did not get error But while opening the chart Null Reference exception is coming. 
        return successMapping;
    }
```

that's way  i am thinking that class object....

Comment: what do you want to achieve? what is your requirement?

Comment: You can only do what you're trying to do if `CustomObject` already implements `IEnumerable`; you can't do that for just any object.

Comment: Is this related to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627426/convert-var-to-listt-in-c-sharp)? You might want to respond to the comments there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a single-element collection (your question is not very clear), you can simply use an array:

```
IEnumerable<CustomObject> data = new []{ itemsSource };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to derive from `IEnumerable` and implement it eventually. This is for cases when you need simply, say, `foreach` over your class instance like if it is a collection of items.

[Implement IEnumerable](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474678/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Implementing-IEnumerable-I).

Other way it just define `this[key]` (indexer) property on your class, so you will be able to use your instance like

```
itemsSource[SOME_KEY]
```

[Using indexer in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Even if your question is not so clear, me too as @ehsan I can't understand what you want to accomplish, I think, starting from the only things you asked, the simplest way to do that is implementing the `IEnumerable` interface, better would be to implement the generic version `IEnumerable<T>` in that way you can enumerate over a well-known-type enumerator with all the advantages you can gain, eg. linq operators support without casting and more.

Another way to accomplish that, a more elegant way without implementing the whole interface at all, should be implementing the *yield pattern* , doing so you can provide a method which returns an enumerator `IEnumerable<T>` and in the method, inside a foreach loop, simply yield returning the current item, this will provide an enumerator support, without implementing the IEnumerable.

just for reference 
[yield usage example & ref](http://www.dotnetperls.com/yield)

Answer (score -1):

So the simple answer is

```
  var enumerable = (IEnumerable)itemsSource;
```

But to give you a correct answer I should know the whole details about CustomObject.